# Understanding the relationship between the spring constant and the angular frequency

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, spring

Suppose, I have a spring whose spring constant is $k_s$, angular frequency is $\omega_s$, and the mass of the object attached at the end of the spring is $m_s$. So, will this be the relationship between the three quantities:

$${\omega_s}^2=\frac{k_s}{m_s}\tag{1}$$

Similarly, if I have an ideal pendulum with a weightless thread, and the mass of the bob is $m_p$ and the pendulum is moving to and fro with angular amplitude $<<4^{\circ}$,

$$F=-k_px\tag{2}$$

the above formula will be applicable for the pendulum since the bob is undergoing simple harmonic motion and the angular frequency will be $\omega_p$. So, will the following be true:

$${\omega_p}^2=\frac{k_p}{m_p}\tag{3}$$

So, are $(1)$ and $(3)$ true?

Answer (score 1):

Since pendulum undergoes rotation around the point at which is suspended, it is more convenient to talk in terms of "Moment which the force exerts (as opposed to talking in terms of force alone)" and in terms of "Moment of inertia (instead of mass, which  we consider for linear motion)".
But the above relation would still hold, i.e.  $\omega_p^2 = \frac{k}{I}$, where here $k$ is proportionality constant between the Moment $M$ and displacement (in this case $\theta$ as opposed to usual $x$), and $I$ is the moment of inertia. Moment that is responsible for driving the bob to equilibrium position is given by $-mgl\sin\theta$ (this is simply force $-mg\sin\theta$ that acts in the direction of motion multiplied by its distance from the point of rotation, which is just length of the pendulum $l$) and for small angles $\sin\theta$ is approximately just $\theta$, so your proportionality constant is $k=-mgl$. If you divide that by $I=ml^2$ you get $\omega_p^2 = \frac{g}{l}$ which is correct expression for frequency of pendulum for small amplitudes. EDIT : Obviously I meant to write $k=mgl$ as $k$ is non-negative.